# Using Tree Set in java with user defined class

Tags: java, set, comparator, treeset

I am trying to add elements of pair in TreeSet, but somehow it is using the comparator to decide which value to be inserted.

```java
class pair{
    int i;
    int j;
    int w;

    pair(int i,int j,int w){
        this.i=i;
        this.j=j;
        this.w=w;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(this==o) return true;
        if(o==null || this.getClass()!=o.getClass()) return false;
        pair p=(pair)o;
        boolean a=i==p.i;
        boolean b=j==p.j;
            boolean c=w==p.w;
        return (a && b && c);
    }

    public int hashCode(Object o){
        return Objects.hash(i,j,w);
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return i + "-" + j + "-" + w;
    }

}
```

```
public class CodeExample {
    
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        TreeSet<pair> s = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<>(){
            public int compare(pair a , pair b){
                return a.w-b.w;
             }
         });
         pair p1 =new pair(1,3,3);
         pair p2 =new pair(1,2,3);
         pair p3 =new pair(2,2,3);
         pair p4 =new pair(2,2,4);

         if(p1.equals(p2))
             System.out.println("P1 and P2 are equal");
         
         s.add(p1);
         s.add(p2);
         s.add(p3);
         s.add(p4);

         System.out.println(s.size()); // OUTPUT = 2
         while(!s.isEmpty()){
             pair t = s.first();
             System.out.println(t); //
             s.remove(t);
         }
    }
}
```

Output

```
2 
1-3-3
2-2-4
```

I am not sure why the p2 and p3 are not being inserted.

If I update the comparator to

```java
TreeSet<pair> s = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<>(){

    public int compare(pair a , pair b){
        if(a.w==b.w ){
            if(a.i==b.i)
                return a.j-b.j;
            return a.i-b.i; 
        }
        return a.w-b.w;
     }
});
```

It is now adding all 4 elements. I thought comparator is only used while removing elements from the Set and the Set uses `equals` and `hashcode` to check if the Objects are duplicate, so why it is not inserting p2 and p3 (Same W value )in the first case?

I'm now sure why it is happening.

Comment: "but somehow it is using the comparator to decide which value to be inserted" Yes, that's how TreeSet works.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html)? Specifically: _"[..], but a `TreeSet` instance performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal."_ It also says: _"Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be **consistent with equals** if it is to correctly implement the Set interface."_